# Binding to a Checkbox inside of a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am trying to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CheckBox` as the sole item in the DataTemplate. I haven't been able to get the binding to work with my view model yet. The binding works as expected with a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, but the problem with the DataGridCheckBoxColumn is that the user has to click twice in order to check/uncheck the checkbox. I have found other posts that suggest using this a CheckBox inside of a DataGridTemplateColumn, and it works as expected in terms of only requiring a single click to operate the checkbox. Now I just need to get the binding.

I would prefer to implement the binding in the xaml rather than in the code-behind.

Here is the relevant xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="BatchRecordParameters">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Extract">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShouldExtract, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<!--    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ShouldExtract}" Header="Extract" />-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterName}" Header="Parameter Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterValue}" Header="Parameter Value" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the above code snippet, the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` is commented out - the binding works for that column, but requires clicking twice on the checkbox. The `Checkbox` has my latest attempt at the binding. I have tried many variations based on different posts I have read.

If it's helpful, the backing property and object in my view model are as follows:

```
public class ParameterData
{
    public bool ShouldExtract { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
}

public IObservableCollection<ParameterData> BatchRecordParameters
{
    get { return batchRecordParameters; }
    set
    {
        batchRecordParameters = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BatchRecordParameters);
    }
}
```

This is a WPF app, and I am using Caliburn.Micro as my MVVM framework. I have found over a dozen posts that address similar issues, but none of the solutions have worked for me. Any help on getting the binding to work is much appreciated!

Comment: I just ran the Xaml through and it works on mine (WOM principle) when I added  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the declaration.  Two way and all!

Comment: DataGridTemplateColumn works perfectly fine. In my case, I am binding it to a collection called FileCollection defined as      private ObservableCollection<MyFileSystemInfo> _fileCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<MyFileSystemInfo> FileCollection
        {
            get { return _fileCollection; }
            set
            {
                _fileCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileCollection");
            }
        }

Comment: All part of the service.  That WOM principle works every time!

Comment: @GarryVass As a follow up question, do you know why this works? I've been reading about the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) property, and according to msdn the CheckBox trigger is supposed to be `PropertyChanged` by default. I wrote a quick test that confirms this, so I'm left wondering why the binding doesn't work unless it is defined explicitly. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't actually need to write a test to find out, the info is explicitly given in the metadata.  mode=two way and property changed.  Anyway.  There is a handler way high up in the visual tree for state changes in IsChecked.  So I *assume* it's wrapped up in the ToggleButton labyrinth.  But that's only a guess!

Comment: @GarryVass - Actually, it's the `DataGridTemplateColumn` that makes all bindings' `UpdateSourceTrigger` "Explicit" by default. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14202491/1869660

Answer (score 0):

1st you will need to inherit from caliburn

```
public class ParameterData : PropertyChangedBase
```

Then Convert your property to implement notification change

```
 public bool ShouldExtract
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shouldExtract;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(this.shouldExtract))
            {
                return;
            }
            this.shouldExtract = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.ShouldExtract);
        }
    }
```

for XAML the code below do just fine

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Extract" Binding="{Binding ShouldExtract}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```